# Distribution of continous random variable

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, random-variables

Given the following

$Y_1 \sim \mathcal{N}(μ, σ^2 )$

and

$Y_2=α+βY_1+U \;where \; Y_1 \;and \;U\;is\;independent\;and\;U∼\mathcal{N}(0,v^2)$

Let $μ=350$ and $σ^2 =12365$

How do i find the distribution of $Y_2$?

Answer (score 1):

If you like, define $Y_3 = \alpha + \beta Y_1$.  Use properties of expectation.  If $E[X] = \mu,$ then because expectation is a linear sum, $E[bX] = b\mu$, and $E[X+c] = \mu + c$   For example, if you double every number, the average will double, and if you add $5$ to every single number, the average goes up by $5$ as well.  Using those, you can find that $Y_3$ is distributed  $N(\alpha + \beta \mu, \beta^2 \sigma^2$)

Now you have a sum $Y_2 = Y_3 + U$ of independent variables.  The mean of a sum is the sum of the means.  The variance of the sum is the sum of the variances for independent variables.  In formulas, $$E[X+Y] = E[X] + E[Y]$$ and $$V[X+Y] = V[X] + V[Y] + Cov[X,Y]$$. and for independent variables, the covariance is zero.  Remember that standard deviation is the square root of the variance.

Comment: Not quite sure i understand this method

Comment: I added more detail for you.

Comment: So what would the mean and variance be in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Using properties of Gaussians, Expectation and variance you get that

$$Y_2\sim N(\alpha+\beta\mu;\beta^2\sigma^2+v^2)$$

Comment: Im not sure i understand this method

Answer (score 0):

The CDF of random variable $Y_2$ is given by
$$
F_{Y_2}(y_2)\equiv P(Y_2\leq y_2)
$$
Therefore,
$$
P(Y_2\leq y_2)=Pr(\alpha+\beta Y_1+U\leq y_2)=Pr(\beta Y_1+U\leq y_2-\alpha)=F_{\beta Y_1+U}(y_2-\alpha).
$$
The sum of normal distributions is normal. Therefore, $\beta Y_1+U\sim N(\beta \mu,\beta^2\sigma^2+v^2)$.